# .NET gRPC - File not found, import proto was not found or had errors, enum is not defined

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I am quite new to the gRPC world and I can't understand and build the project because it is saying that file is not found and the import is not correct. I want to make the models reusable.

[image: Errors]

greet.proto file here:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "DemoAppGrpc";

package greet;

import "Enums/gameType.proto";

service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
  GameType gameType = 2;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

gameType.proto file type here:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "DemoAppGrpc";

package greet;

enum GameType {
  None = 0;
  Open = 1;
  Free = 2;
}
```

My project/folder structure that I want to have:

[image]

And my project solution file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\*.proto" GrpcServices="Server">
          <GrpcServices>Server</GrpcServices>
          <Access>Public</Access>
          <ProtoCompile>True</ProtoCompile>
          <CompileOutputs>True</CompileOutputs>
          <OutputDir>obj\Debug\net6.0\</OutputDir>
          <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
        </Protobuf>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.40.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

So how can I achieve to import nested files?

Comment: Add `ProtoRoot="Protos"`

Comment: @HansPassant - I added that and now I have another error: The type or namespace name 'GameType' does not exist in the namespace 'DemoAppGrpc' (are you missing an assembly reference?) from the auto-generated class `Greet.cs`

Comment: You need to use the package namespace for the message in the other proto package. I think one problem is trying to use the same package name in both proto files, but they are not in the same directory.  If they were together, you would have no trouble. If you want to keep them separate, you can, but they should have different package names, and you'd refer to the message as `otherpackage.GameType` instead.